# Is it possible to upgrade from CentOS 5.6 to 6?

Tags: centos5

Is it possible to upgrade from CentOS 5.6 to 6 ?

Comment: "Short answer: 'Yes' with an 'If,' long answer: 'No' -- with a 'But.'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's theoretically possible to upgrade from 5.6 to 6.

No, I can't predict what'll happen if you try, but you might want to snapshot the state and try it in a virtual machine.  I found some anecdotal forum posts by googling "upgrading centos 5.6 to 6.x" but none of them filled me with faith.

Minor versions are usually fine, but I'd preferentially do a clean install when changing major versions of *anything*.

Answer (score 4):

Since CentOS is based on RHEL you can trust their official statement too. In the official [Installation Guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-upgrade-x86.html) they write that an upgrade of a major version is not recommended. But they give you a guide how to do it and what you have to take care of.

Comment: Just as a datum, I have done this with a **clean, freshly-installed** C5.7 box, as a test, and it upgraded fine.  How it would go on a box that's been in service for some years, and was indeed upgraded in-place from C4, I'll find out in about a month, when I do it.

Comment: @MadHatter Thank you for the update. I was thinking about trying it out too.